# Live update of big datagrid cells: approaches

Tags: javascript, html, css, datagrid

Let's imagine a scrollable datagrid (a table) with a big amount of rows. For example a list of user's opened trades (positions) in stock market. Each quote we need to update a cells of current position's profit. I know 2 bad approaches:

1. Redraw the table. (Very slow and ineffective whith when we have tons of rows inside.
2. Update cell directly throw selector (id, etc.) giving due to initial rows rendering. Faster than #1 but still slow because of browser layout and styles recalculation.
   Obviously the problem is slow DOM, i guess.

I'm sure this is a typical issue and good approaches have to be exist. What it may be? Hide rows (via display: none;) which currently out of visible range and recalculate that on each onScroll? Or smth like that.
Thank for your attention.

Comment: Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306310/how-to-hide-content-not-in-vissible-view-on-a-page-with-many-html-elements-to-im/50313602#50313602)

Comment: this css hook is already implemented in my table. Anyway their example is also slow very much...

Comment: Is it ok for you to only show some rows to the user (juste enough to fill the page) ? and also is it ok for you to use external tool ?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami 1. no, big table is scrollable; 2. no, i need just idea, not a ready solution.